# How to access the code of a game (even if it is obfuscated) when a game is protected?

Tags: javascript, html

http://atwar-game.com/ <- talking about this game. Is it normal that I can't access the code with inspect element or f12? How did they do it? Is there a way to bypass the protection?

Comment: first time i see something like this

Comment: Try it in Firefox devtools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTTP Proxy tools like Fiddler to intercept HTTP traffic.